# 1C 8.3 Сброс пароля

Tags: 1с

Server 2008 R2 Enterprise
SQL Server 10.50.2500

Есть доступ к серверу, нету пароля от администратора 1С.

Есть рабочие способы сбросить\узнать пароль от аккаунта админа или добавить нового админа?

Comment: 1c version - 8.3.7.1805

Comment: Очевидно, что добавить нового админа может не кто попало, а тот кто обладает на это права. Тоже самое со сбросом пароля. Если бы любому пользователю это можно было делать, то не было бы никакой безопасности.

Comment: @iluxa1810, в базе можно тупо дропнуть таблицу с пользователям, потом зайти под конфигуратором и добавить пользователей заново (в деталях могу ошибаться, но смысл такой). Пароли "защищают" только при внешнем доступе к базе. Если же есть админский доступ к sql серверу, они никак не защитят.

Comment: @insolor - это да, но мне покказалось, что доступ не админский.

Comment: Доступ как раз от админа

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Гугль помог

Первый запрос SQL Server Management

```
EXEC sp_rename 'v8users', 'v8users_tmp'
GO
UPDATE [Params]
SET [FileName] = 'users.usr_tmp'
WHERE [FileName] = 'users.usr'
GO
```

Открыл конфигуратор

Второй запрос SQL Server Management

```
DROP TABLE [v8users]
GO
EXEC sp_rename 'v8users_tmp', 'v8users'
GO
UPDATE [Params]
SET FileName = 'users.usr'
WHERE FileName = 'users.usr_tmp'
GO
```

И добавил себя и права соответственно

И все